# Browser local storage missing after Patreon redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, redirect, local-storage

I have a simple webpage which uses client-side scripts to store a few user configs in browser local storage. (Status of checkboxes, expanded/collapsed menus, etc.)

I have a Patreon button on my webpage. When the user clicks it, the user's browser navigates to a Patreon authentication page and, if the user clicks a button to grant me access to their user support status, Patreon redirects their browser to a route on my site where I record their support status and then redirect them back to my home page.

When the user finally lands back at my home page, all of the user's local storage data is missing. If the user clicks Refresh after landing back at my site, local storage is still missing. However, if they close the tab and open my site in a new tab (or navigate to another site and then navigate back in the same tab), the original local storage values are visible again.

I understand that browser local storage is associated with the origin of the local storage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

I have confirmed that both the protocol (https) and the domain are identical for the point where storage is set and the point when the user returns to my site. I have also confirmed that the final landing route is identical.

home page where local storage values are initially set: `https://www.example.com/page1`
final landing page: `https://www.example.com/page1`

I noticed that if I stop the user at the Patreon redirect route (where Patreon initially redirects users and where I record user support status), opening the browser debugger and issuing `document.domain` gives: `""`

However, setting document.domain and refreshing does not restore the local storage.

I am seeing this behavior in both Firefox 63.0.3 (64-bit) and Chrome 71.0.3578.80 (64-bit).

Any ideas what I could be missing?

[EDIT] Here is the code I'm using to write the user state to local storage:

```
if(localStorage.userOptions){ restoreOptsFromLocal(); }
else{ persistOptsToLocal(); }
...
restoreOptsFromLocal = function(){
    opts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userOptions'));
}
persistOptsToLocal = function(){ 
    localStorage.setItem('userOptions', JSON.stringify(opts));
}
```

Comment: My first thought is that your local storage isn't setup to work on http/https, but you've confirmed the user starts at https and ends at https. Are you 100% sure the protocol is correct? A redirect shouldn't do anything, but perhaps your code clears local storage on page load? Can you share that portion of your code, where you save to localstorage?

Comment: Sure thing, added as an edit above. There's not much there, tbh. opts is a javascript object with a few attributes. Also, I've confirmed that the local storage item does exists before user leaves to Patreon.

Comment: Are you checking for the existence of `localStorage.getItem('userOptions')` before you write to it? That could be what's wiping it out.

Comment: Yes, I'll add the full code. I'm certain the local storage items are persisting and are not being overwritten by my code. I've been using and debugging the page for several months now without any trouble. The problem only recently popped up when I added the Patreon button. Also, if the user closes the tab and opens my page in a new tab, the original local storage objects appear again. I really suspect there is some weirdness going on with the protocol-domain-port tuple during the redirect, but I'm not positive.

Comment: How soon after you save to `localStorage` do you redirect with Patreon? saving to `localStorage` is an asynchronous call, so if both happen at the same time, it won't save it in time. If so, you can use `window.onbeforeunload = function() {localStorage.setItem()}`

Comment: Interesting. Didn't think about writing to localStorage being async. But the data's definitely being persisted. Reading/writing to localStorage happens immediately on page init, while the redirect from Patreon happens only when user clicks the Patreon button. Those two events could be separated any amount of time. 5 seconds to 10 mins or more. And again, if the user closes the tab and opens my page in a new tab, the old localStorage values (written before the user navigated away to Patreon) reappear, with all values set where the user left them.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a few hours hunting and debugging, still don't understand the root cause. Current workaround is to set the Patreon href's target to "_blank" so that the patreon authentication process takes place in a separate window.